# Is there a more efficient way to run enum values through a switch-case statement in C# than this?

Tags: c#, performance, switch-statement

I was wondering if there was a more efficient (efficient as in simpler/cleaner code) way of making a case statement like the one below...

I have a dictionary. Its key type is an Enum and its value type is a bool. If the boolean is true, I want to change the color of a label on a form.

The variable names were changed for the example.

```
Dictionary<String, CustomType> testDict = new Dictionary<String, CustomType>();

//populate testDict here...

Dictionary<MyEnum, bool> enumInfo = testDict[someString].GetEnumInfo(); 
//GetEnumInfo is a function that iterates through a Dictionary<String, CustomType>
//and returns a Dictionary<MyEnum, bool>

            foreach (KeyValuePair<MyEnum, bool> kvp in enumInfo)
            {
                switch (kvp.Key)
                {
                    case MyEnum.Enum1:
                        if (someDictionary[kvp.Key] == true)
                        {
                            Label1.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Label1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                        }
                        break;
                    case MyEnum.Enum2:
                       if (someDictionary[kvp.Key] == true)
                        {
                            Label2.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Label2.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                        }
                        break;
               }
           }
```

So far, MyEnum has 8 different values.. which means I have 8 different case statements.. 
I know there must be an easier way to do this, I just can't conceptualize it in my head.

If anyone could help, I'd greatly appreciate it. I love C# and I learn new things every day.. I absorb it like a sponge :)

-CP

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just switch the label, and then set the colors after the switch statement:

```
Label label = null;
switch (kvp.Key)
{
    case MyEnum.Enum1:
        label = Label1;
        break;
    case MyEnum.Enum2:
        label = Label2;
        break;
}

label.ForeColor = kvp.Value ? Color.LimeGreen : Color.Red;
```

Alternatively, you could have a `Dictionary<MyEnum, Label>`, and just lookup the label appropriately:

```
labelDictionary[kvp.Key].ForeColor = kvp.Value ? Color.LimeGreen : Color.Red;
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! I knew I could've used the ternary operator to save quite a bit of space.. I just hadn't thought of creating a dictionary containing the labels. Much appreciation! :)

Answer (score 2):

Create a hash table that maps from your enum values to the label.  Then you can just look up the label to change, rather than switch.

Answer (score 2):

Create a map between the enum and the label that needs to be changed based on that enum value.  Then use the current enum value to get the corresponding label to update.

```
Dictionary<MyEnum,Label> labelMap = new Dictionary<MyEnum,Label>();
labelMap.Add( MyEnum.Enum1, Label1 );
...


foreach (KeyValuePair<MyEnum, bool> kvp in enumInfo)  
{  
    var label = labelMap[kvp.Key];
    label.ForeColor = kvp.Value ? Color.LimeGreen : Color.Red;
}
```

Comment: @tvanfosson: Completely off-topic, but congrats on breaking 100k!

Comment: Ah, thank you. This is pretty what I wanted. I appreciate it, and grats on 100k ;)

Answer (score 1):

First, you may want to consolidate the body of the case statements into a function that accepts one or more parameters. This may be easier than duplicating content. *@Reed's idea of selecting the right label instance in the switch statement is also a good idea, and if the logic only varies on this basis, be a better choice.*

You can also use the ?: operator to simplify the decision logic.

For example:

```
switch (kvp.Key) 
            { 
                case MyEnum.Enum1: 
                    UpdateUI( Label1, someDictionary[kvp.Key] );
                    break; 
                case MyEnum.Enum2: 
                    UpdateUI( Label2, someDictionary[kvp.Key] );
                    break; 
                case MyEnum.Enum3: 
                    UpdateUI( Label3, someDictionary[kvp.Key] );
                    break; 
            }

public void UpdateUI( Label theLabel, bool whichOne )
{
     theLabel.ForeColor = whichOne ? Color.LimeGreen : Color.Red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just put your cases in a dictionary:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
class Program
{
    private enum MyEnum
    {
        shwan,
        dooo,
        sieven,
        sieven_haif,
        shwenty,
        shwenty_doo_haif,
        schfifty_faive
    }

    class EnumInfo
    {
        public MyEnum Enum;
        public bool State;

        public override bool  Equals(object obj)
        {
            EnumInfo ei = obj as EnumInfo;
            return this.Enum == ei.Enum && this.State == ei.State;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return this.Enum.GetHashCode() ^ this.State.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

    private static IDictionary<EnumInfo, Color> EnumColorDict = new Dictionary<EnumInfo, Color>()
        {
            {new EnumInfo(){Enum=MyEnum.shwan, State=true},Color.LimeGreen},
            {new EnumInfo(){Enum=MyEnum.shwan, State=false},Color.Red},
            {new EnumInfo(){Enum=MyEnum.dooo, State=true},Color.LimeGreen},
            {new EnumInfo(){Enum=MyEnum.dooo, State=false},Color.Red}
        };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        EnumInfo ei = new EnumInfo() { Enum = MyEnum.shwan, State = true };

        Color c = EnumColorDict[ei];
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hilarious enum names! That song's so old.. gives me flashbacks of an early last decade ;)

I'm going with the accepted answer at the top as it reduced the lines of code from 80ish to 7 :)

thanks a lot

Comment: Well I made my answer into a program, and it's 55 lines, so if you subtract things that you already have in your program like: usings, MyEnum, Main function, it's probably not much longer, and I'd say it's more readable.

Either way...